# Error connecting to mongoDB using Mongolite

Tags: r, mongodb, database-connection, mongolite, libmongoc

I'm having issues connecting to my MongoDB via Mongolite, and I'm not sure if it is an issue on my side, or if I need to use a different package to connect to the database. Please keep in mind that I cannot change the software being run by the MongoDB server, and I am a novice when it comes to all of this, so it could just be a silly error on my part.

I've run the following code:

```
m <- mongo(collection = "test", url="mongodb://22.92.59.149:27017")
```

As far as I can tell from the Mongolite tutorial (https://jeroen.github.io/mongolite/), this is the correct syntax to connect to the database, but I'm not 100% sure. Regardless, I get the following error:

```
Error: Server at 22.92.59.149:27017 reports wire version 2, 
but this version of libmongoc requires at least 3 (MongoDB 3.0)
```

From what I can tell, this means that mongolite won't work with my database. If that is the case, what other package should I try to use to connect, or if it is not the issue what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the message says, there is a mismatch between versions of the client and the server.

More precisely, `mongolite` relies on a more general driver written in C, `libmongoc`, and it seems the version automatically installed by the `install.packages("mongolite")` statement is too recent towards the server's version.

If you can't change anything server-side, maybe you could try to [manually install](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/installing.html#install-libmongoc-with-a-package-manager) an older version of `libmongoc` before installing `mongolite`, but I'm not confident about the compatibility with that R package afterwards.

Maybe you can use [RMongo](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RMongo/versions/0.0.25/topics/RMongo-package), an older and [archived](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RMongo/) package to interact with Mongo in R, but I'm afraid what you're going to develop won't be stable in further R versions.

I'd rather recommend you to look at the problem server side.

Comment: Thanks, theplatypus. I'll take a look into fixing the issue server side, and if I can't find a way to update it then I will give an older version of libmongoc or RMongo a try.